# How to replace current CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos

I have a simple application in swift. It has a function that returns a CALayer which is a layer with gradient background.

When a button is clicked I use this code:

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(myGradientLayer, at: 0)
```

Which works fine and draws properly. However if i later want to change the color by clicking the second button I can no longer change the color of the layer at index 0. If I use same code nothing happens. What am i missing? And yes i call the view.setNeedsDisplay()

Comment: Yes, because your previous layer is going to be on top...
How ? well there is many options to solve this...
Wha about to have CALayer as a member and to color it, while inserting it only once in the init or something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the documentations `The sublayers are listed in back to front order.`so each time you add a layer at index 0 then it will be below your previous one. The first layer works with you because it's the only layer but any layer you put at index 0 after it will be below the first layer

Answer (score 4):

Both the answers here were correct. Much appreciated.

The answer is:

```
view.layer.sublayers?[0].removeFromSuperLayer()
view.layer.insertSubLayer(MyLayer, at: 0)
view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

So I need to add a layer in the init method like one of the answers suggests before I can actually call the above methods.

Comment: This is the best and most obvious/simple answer! I've also gone as far as naming my sublayer and then removing it by name

Answer (score 2):

I would go as far as naming my sublayer `myLayer.name = "myLayer"` and then having a function that I would call before replacing another layer with it.

```
    _ = layer.sublayers?.map {
        if $0.name == "myLayer" {
           $0.removeFromSuperlayer()
       }
    }
    layer.insertSublayer(myLayer, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Come across this question when I need a similar function.
My final solution is to define a new class `MyCALayer` that inherits `CALayer`

```
class MyCALayer : CALayer {
     var tag:Int?
     override init() {
         super.init()
     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
     }
}
```

Then when create the layer, assign a tag to it. Next time when you need to replace it, you can loop all the view's sublayers and found the corresponding layer added previously.

```
  if let sublayers = view.layer.sublayers {
        for layer in sublayers {
            if let mylayer = layer as? MyCALayer,
                mylayer.tag == tag {
                mylayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }
    }
```

Share it in case anyone else has the similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `replaceSublayer(_ oldLayer: CALayer, with newLayer: CALayer)` method:

```
view.layer.replaceSublayer(theOldLayer, with: newLayer)
```

The code above replaces the old view with the new one.